# Linq query never returns

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have faced a weird problem, and stuck for last 2 hours on it. I have a simplest `Linq` query, that gets all users from `UserProfile` table, and maps it to new `UserViewModel`. but the weird thing is, **it never returns**.
The highlighted section in image below is the position of debugger. once it enters this area, it never returns.

To make it more clear, I tried to get a single user from `UserProfile` table in variable `prof`, and tried to get all users in `profiles`, it works fine (first two lines). both variables are populated. but from same table, i'm querying all users and mapping it `UserViewModel`, query doesn't work. It really never returns. Table contains only 10 users.

[image]

Am i missing something? actually query was complex. It has joins with `Roles` etc. I was trying different ways to join tables. but later when i tried to comment other joins, and making query simplest, i was shocked, it is not even giving all users without any condition.

(VS2012, EF 5.0)

Comment: Looks like you're silently ignoring some exception. I'm not sure if EF will accept this cast and this "Dispatcher" thing. Try to remove properties from the anon. type until you get results.

Comment: Is the cast (ActiveInactiveCatalog) valid? Do you get any error, if you try to run your code without mapping like this:
`var users = _DBContex.UserProdiles.Select(u => new UserViewModel());`

Comment: @GertArnold and @cSteusloff, Thank you for your attention. Yes, with your help, I figured it out. `IsActive` column in DB was null, and i was expecting it to be `1`, and hence cast it accordingly. It is really very silent exception.